How can I see the value a function returned using CLion's debugger
I'm using CLion 2024.2 to debug a program. I know that, a couple of years back, JetBrains supposedly implemented the capability of showing function return values: CLion bug CPP-5130. I've even enabled this, in the Debug panel left-side gearhweel: Toggled "Show Function Return Values.
But I don't see the return value(s) anywhere :-(  ... where are they?
Related:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5130
